# Open Graph FB Authentication not returning valid token in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm working on a facebook login and trying to log in. Clicking a LoginButton gives me a prompt to log in with facebook, but oncomplete does not return a valid token.

I have attached the error:

The main idea: The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App

> I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: {
>   "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid",
>   "message": "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook:
>   {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not
>   match the Viewing
>   App\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"GWc2S2d1RWT\"}}"
>   } ], "code": 400, "message": "Unsuccessful debug_token response from
>   Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) The App_id in the
>   input_token did not match the Viewing
>   App\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"GWc2S2d1RWT\"}}"
>   } }

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't highlight that part, but how do I correct this error/why does the problem stem from?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'd try Facebook Dev documentation

Comment: Make sure you set the correct app id and app secret in whatever places that gets configured in your app/framework.

Answer (score -1):

https://medium.com/@puthnith/firebase-for-ios-invalid-api-key-cdde76ff92c4
This solved my problem.

1. Goto Firebase -> Project Settings -> Add firebase to your iOS App(If there is no iOS App added).
2. Download the GoogleService-Info.plist and into your iOS project just below Info.plist on the root of Xcode Project.

Comment: The question is about Facebook, not Firebase.